# Key stroking fn + f8

Tags: keyboard, applescript

I need to make an applescript to press the keys fn + f8 at the same time. The only problem is those are both keys without names!

```
tell application "System Events"
    key code 63 -- Will press the fn key
    key code 100 -- Will press the f8 key
end tell
```

However, how can I get these two key strokes to happen simultaneously? I cant seem to do key code 63 with 100 down or any variation. Help?

Comment: did you consider using the key down and key up commands rather than keystrokes?

Answer (score 1):

Key code 100 is actually F8, If you want to press F8 key just send key code 100. 
But a different media control command key. Unfortunately, it seems the only way to run the pause command in media players via applescript is to send the proper key directly to the application(i.e. iTunes and Spotify). please see:

https://gist.github.com/NoobsArePeople2/5121597

PS: If you want to check press <kbd>Fn</kbd>, you can run this script

```
delay (1.0)
tell application "System Events"
    key code 63 -- fn
    key code 63 -- fn
end tell
```

this press <kbd>Fn</kbd> key two times and trigger the dictation